# Could Faulty Memory Cause Unreported Errors

Tags: memory

I have been occasionally seeing these memory errors:
"Uncorrectable memory error has been previously detected in RISER DIMM X".

It only happened twice in the past half a year. When it happens, the system crashes and the message is reported at the next boot. The error then goes away - it does not seem to be repeatable.

There is no question that something is wrong. A web search shows that it is either my memory or motherboard that's at fault. But given the intermittent nature of the problem, it's very hard to figure out what it is, and whether it will impact my usage.

Question: If the system does not crash, is it possible that my programs could be producing incorrect results? For example, if I'm running a database or computation program, is it possible that sometimes the programs could generate erroneous results without the system crashing, and I would never know about it?

If so, the fact the problem is intermittent is particularly worrisome, as I would not know when the program is producing correct results and when it's not.

Comment: You have ran several runs of memtestx86?

Comment: No, I'll do that and see what turns up. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is very possible, although it’s unlikely the system wouldn’t crash regularly with a permanent memory error. While memory management is deterministic, the way you use your computer isn’t. ;) That way, programs (and their working set) will appear in different memory locations nearly every time you start them.

Faulty memory can (and will) also result in disk corruption, when data marked for DMA transfer to a disk is corrupted in-memory. This is, in my opinion, much more dangerous, because you may not notice these errors for years, until you need the data and find it corrupted.

Comment: It turns out I have ECC memory. Is this type of memory less prone to problems of erroneous program output and disk corruption?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Regular ECC memory can detect up to two errors per 64 bit word and correct a single error per 64 bit word. That may mean that most errors are repaired automatically for you. I don’t know where you would find information on that though, because I never had an ECC-equipped system myself.